# change name of HTML <select> form Attribute in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, forms, sinatra

In my code I create duplicate copies of a fieldset based on user input using the code in the snippet. My issue right now is that when the user submits the form the params Hash does not take into account value from different instances of the fieldset. The last value overwrites all the previous values. As an example in the current scenario below is the params Hash.

```
 { "member"=>"2", "lte_freq1"=>"4", "ru_type"=>"RRU", "4_way_rx"=>"No"}
```

However, my desired output is shown below. Here the value of member =2 so two instances of fieldset are appended:

```
 { "member"=>"2", "lte_freq1_1"=>"6", "ru_type_1"=>"RU", 
  "4_way_rx_1"=>"Yes", "lte_freq1_2"=>"4", "ru_type_2"=>"RRU", 
  "4_way_rx_2"=>"No" }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
var repeat = $('fieldset');
var cloned;

for (i=1;i<number;i++){
    cloned = repeat.clone(true);
    cloned.appendTo('.sector_prop');

}


 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>                                                                   
<br>

 <br>
 <br>

</head>
<body>
<form action="/form" method="post">
<div class="textbox">



<legend><b> RF Parameters</b></legend>
<br>
Number of Sectors (LTE)<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
<br>
<br>




<button>Generate Sector Properties</button>
<br>
<br>

<div class="sector_prop">

<fieldset>
Primary LTE Carrier (Select lowest frequency on the site 850 for Band 5, AWS 
for Band 4 and PCS for Band 2)<br>
<br>
<select name="lte_freq1">
<option value="6">850</option>
<option value="2">AWS</option>
<option value="4">PCS</option>
</select>
<br>


<br>
Radio Type (Select "RU" for Rack-mount or RRU for Remote-Radio):<br>
<br>
<select name="ru_type">
  <option value="RU">RU</option>
  <option value="RRU">RRU</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
4 way Rx (Select "Yes" or "No"):<br>
<br>
<select name="4_way_rx">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
 

</fieldset>

</div>

<br>



<input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cloning the element, it won't magically update the field name. So you need to manually get the index and update the name of the new element as you clone:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
    var repeat = $('fieldset');
    var cloned;

    for (i=1;i<number;i++){
      cloned = repeat.clone(true);
      current_name = cloned.find('select').attr('name');
      cloned.find('select').prop('name', current_name + '_' + i);
      cloned.appendTo('.sector_prop');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim for your suggestion. one more question - what if I have multiple select elements inside the clone. your implementation will find the first match of 'select' and perform the concat. How can I do this for multiple select elements ?